# How to force the urlUtils proxy perform only POST requests

Tags: arcgis-10.2, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, proxy

How can I force the   [urlUtils](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.urlutils-amd.html) to use only POST requests.
I a using it as shown in the following block described also in [the how to use proxy section](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html), and I have noticed that some times (maybe when the request is less than 2000 characters ) it performs GET request, which in my case is not an accepted solution.

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
urlPrefix: "route.arcgis.com",
proxyUrl: "<url_to_proxy>"
});
```

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree.  The web requests themselves determine whether a GET or POST is submitted, not the proxy rule.  In `esri.request` this means specifying `usePost:true` in the request JSON. On dojo forms it means using `form.method = "post"`. Without the relevant code it's impossible to answer beyond 'You can't.'

Comment: I have created a proxy on my own .. that hears on post requests. An I would like to avoid GETs. I know how the web works. But I would expect that arcgis and urlUtils could provide such a capability.

Comment: urlUtils doesn't, because that's not its purpose. The JSAPI does, because I use it.  You haven't provided a query, so no one can show you how to specify a POST method.

Answer (score 1):

Vince is correct the best way is to use the JSAPI to specify usePost:true.

docs at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html

the only other way to force the SDK to generate a post is to ensure that the query string is over 2000 characters by appending some meaningless values such as where="1=1 and 1=1"